# Given two absolute paths A and B, how to get the relative path from A to B

Tags: c++, include-path

I have a programm which generates a header and a source file, both can be stored in different directionaries from each other. I want to have the header file as an include in the source file, here is my problem how can I construct the include such that it's working even if they are in completly different dirs?

E.g. source path: `C:/AA/BB/EE/source.cpp` , header path: `C:/AA/CC/DD/header.h` => `#include "../../CC/DD/header.h` (No absolut paths in the include, no use of third party libraries).

My current idea is that I split both paths between the slashes, put them into an array and compare them, but I can't figure out the rest.

Comment: std::filesystem has some functions you can use. E.g [filesystem::relative](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/relative) and proximate

Comment: _directionarys_ == _directories_?

Comment: so your question boils down to "Given two absolute paths A and B, how to get the relative path from A to B", right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `std::filesystem::relative`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <filesystem>

int main() {
    auto p = std::filesystem::relative("a/b/c/d","a/b/x/y");
    std::cout << p;
}
```

[Output](https://godbolt.org/z/s3YYP6bG7):

```
"../../c/d"
```

Comment: Yes this would be the wanted output, but would something like that be possible without using filesystem?

Comment: @saiko c++14 `std::experimental::filesystem` doesnt have relative paths afaik

Answer (score 0):

without filesystem:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>

using namespace std;

template <typename out>
void split( const std::string &s, char delimeter, out result ) {
    std::istringstream iss( s );
    std::string item;
    while( std::getline( iss, item, delimeter ) ) {
        *result++ = item;
    }
}

std::vector<std::string> split( const std::string &s, char delimeter ) {
    std::vector<std::string> elems;
    split( s, delimeter, std::back_inserter( elems ) );
    return elems;
}

int main() {
    string source_file = "C:/AA/BB/EE/source.cpp";
    string header_file = "C:/AA/CC/DD/header.h";
    string include = "";
    string extra = "";
    std::vector<std::string> cpp = split( source_file, '/' );
    std::vector<std::string> hpp = split( header_file, '/' );
    std::vector<std::string>::iterator c = cpp.begin();
    std::vector<std::string>::iterator h = hpp.begin();
    while( *h == *c && *c != *cpp.end()  && *h != *hpp.end() ) {
        h++;
        c++;
    }
    while( *c != *cpp.end() ) {
        if( *c != *cpp.rbegin() ) {
            include += "../";
        }
        c++;
    }
    while( *h != *hpp.end() ) {
        if( *h == *hpp.rbegin() ) {
            include += extra;
            include += *hpp.rbegin();
        } else {
            extra += *h;
            extra += "/";
        }
        h++;
    }
    std::cout << include << endl;
}
```

But personally, I like `std::filesystem::relative` better, +1 for @
463035818_is_not_an_ai

Comment: Doesn't seem to work, the split is fine but the include and extra are always empty.

Comment: In my case it shows: ../../CC/DD/header.h
Did you use the same filenames? or something with backslashes, in that case the split delimiter, and all other forward slashes, have to be '\\'

Comment: Well I just copied the whole thing to try it out.

Comment: Got it to work, the problem was in the while loops need to compare the values there instead of the iterators.